# MysqlQuery wild card from string

Tags: php, mysql, string, wildcard

`$value` is grabbed from checkboxset from previous .php

```
$value = $_POST['checkbox_value'];  
$value = implode('', $value); // since it's an array I convert it to a string
```

`$value` is now defined as `*N*O*` (5-letter string)

```
$percent = '%';
$value = str_replace('*', $percent, $value); // that's being desperate already

$query = $FirstPartOfQuery. " AND word LIKE '{$value}'";
```

That should produce a working code for my query

```
AND (word LIKE 'C%' AND word LIKE '%N%O%')
```

It is exactly what my query prints, but it's not working.

But if i define `$value = '%N%O%';` manually, it's fine and it compiles.

My guess is, that the posted value, after converting into a string is not being read as a single quoted string.

I thought `%` was causing upset, therefore I used `*` in `checkbox_value` instead to check. No help.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work: 
$query = $FirstPartOfQuery. " AND word LIKE '".$value."'".")";

Comment: echo $query ; and say what is passing?

Comment: what $FirstPartOfQuery.  contains ?

Comment: @VigneswaranS full query: SELECT wyraz FROM wyrazy WHERE wyraz_id < 371371 AND wyraz_length IN('7') AND ( wyraz LIKE 'C%' AND wyraz LIKE '%N%O%') AND wyraz_base = '0' AND bazo = '1' AND ndm = '0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100000

Comment: @VigneswaranS But as I said, if I define $value myself, it compiles just fine. It's weird.

Comment: run this and see $value = $_POST['checkbox_value']; print_r($value);exit();?

Comment: i think problem is with implode .or array ?

Comment: you ther can you say ?what is printing ?

Comment: It prints: `Array ( [0] => *N*O* )`

Comment: @VigneswaranS So even if I grab: $value = $_POST['checkbox_value'];
$value = $value['0']; It still isn't working, even though it prints problematic part of query as  (word LIKE 'C%' AND word LIKE '%N%O%') (correctly)

Answer (score 0):

if your implode('',$value) ; gives *N*0** value then str_replace(*,%,$value) will result in %N%0%%. so check $_post[];array properly.

```
<?php
$value="*N*0**";
$percent = '%';
$value = str_replace('*', $percent, $value); 

$second= "  AND word LIKE  '$value' )";
$FirstPartOfQuery="(word LIKE 'C%' ";
$query = $FirstPartOfQuery. $second ;
echo "AND ". $query;//AND (word LIKE 'C%' AND word LIKE '%N%0%%' )
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After debbuging my code, problem turned out to be a missing `;` in end portion of  my .php, where bloody `eval` was used and it only was passed, when  `$_POST['checkbox_value'];` was definied.

Therefore, there was no problem with the question asked.

Sorry and thank you @VigneswaranS for your effort and time.